# I am not able to use setValue funtion of react-hook even I am providing the right arguments and it is giving me error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am building a dynamic form in which I am using react-hook-form for registering the data, I ahave used two models one for fetching data from api which is DewFormdetail and FormDataset for storing the responses but I am not able to use setValue() function for registering input fields like date , and radio button

```
  answerField = (
    <div className="answer-field" key={`answer-field-${index}`}>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DatePicker
          className="date-picker"
          slotProps={{ textField: { placeholder: "Please select date" } }}
          format="MM/DD/YYYY"
          {...reg(
            formdetail.QuestionId.toString() as `responses.${string}`
          )}
          onChange={(dateItem: String) => {
            setV(
              formdetail.QuestionId.toString() as `responses.${string}`,
              dateItem)
            );
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

this is where I am trying to use setv(setValue) function

here are models : -

```
export  interface DewFormDetail {
QuestionId: number;
FormId : number ;
QuestionNo : number;
Question : string;
QuestionType : 'Text' | 'email' | 'Number' | 'radio';
Options : string;
isMandatory : Boolean;}

 useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(questions) && questions.length > 0) {
      questions.forEach((item) => {
        setValue(item.QuestionId.toString(), "parth");
      });
    }
  }, [questions, setValue]);
```

Comment: its giving me this error Argument of type 'String' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' , even I am intialising values like this   useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(questions) && questions.length > 0) {
      questions.forEach((item) => {
        setValue(item.QuestionId.toString(), "parth");
      });
    }
  }, [questions, setValue]);

Comment: Could you add to the question how you are initializing `setV`? Also in the comment above you use `setValue` in the question you use `setV`. Are those the same?

Comment: yes setv and set value are same , I am using form component and field component and field components consists of required text fields , radio button so I am sending setValue as a prop to fields and named it as setV inside fields component